# possible lossy conversion float to int in foreach-loop

Tags: java, foreach, type-conversion

I was trying to write the following code that is supposed to calculate the average of all numbers in an array, and we're supposed to use the foreach-loop!
The problem is that the compiler tells me about lossy conversions from float to int in line 3 ("    for(int k: numbers)" ).

Casting k to float doesn't work, casting numbers doesn't work ('f course), and casting everything else doesn't seem to work either!
Where is the problem, please help!

Thanks in advance!

```
float calculateAverage(float[] numbers){
    float a = 0.0f;
    for(int k: numbers){
        (a) = a+numbers[k];
    }
    return a/(numbers.length-1);

}
```

Comment: looks like a homework. In most languages, you cannot "do something" with the left-side of the assignment, just the right side...

Comment: And this is java I suppose. It would be best to add a tag for the language that you are using,

Comment: You're using an enhanced `for` loop. That doesn't use the counter variable to access the `numbers` array. It holds each _member_ of the `numbers` array within its local variable in turn as it iterates over the loop. So, `k` would need to be a `float` as your array is an array of type `float[]`. At the first iteration of the loop, the first value in `numbers` will be held in `k`. You can do your cumulative addition into `a` with that then perform the division at the end as you have done.

Comment: yep thanks, that was the problem, the for each loop has to be read as
"for each float out of array numbers", while i thought k would be the index, like its used in any other for loop!
thanks for the aid!!

Answer (score 0):

So, here you hold each element of `numbers` in `k` in turn, adding them into `a`. You then return the value of `a` divided by the number of elements in the array:

```
float calculatedAverage(float[] numbers){
    float a = 0.0f;
    for (float k : numbers) {
        a += k;
    }
    return a / numbers.length;
}
```

The enhanced `for` loop doesn't use a counter variable so there's no need to be accessing `numbers[]` with an index.